# Run two different laravel projects with same domain NGINX

Tags: nginx

I'm using nginx as my webserver.

Case1 : learning.test/ -------> Redirect to my Laravel app

Case2 : learning.test/whatever/ -------> Redirect to my app too

Case3: learning.test/test/ -------> Redirect to my another Laravel project

My Nginx configuration file is:

```
server {
listen 80;
#listen [::]:80;

client_max_body_size 32M;

fastcgi_buffers 128 2048k;
fastcgi_buffer_size 2048k;

index index.php index.html;

root /home/paul/personal/NewLearningProject/public;

server_name learning.test;

location ^~ /test {
    root /home/paul/MazeGeek/Laravel8;
    index index.php;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /blog/index.php;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
    }
}

location ~ /\.ht {
deny all;
}
}
```

I'm having (NGINX 404 Not Found) error for both Case2 and Case3